# ListView and CollectionView are taking extra space than the required space in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a `string[]` array that displays items using `Label`. I am using a `ListView` for this purpose. It is working fine, the only problem is that the `ListView` is taking extra space than that is required. I have also tried with `CollectionView` but the same problem persists.

Please note that my `ListView` is under `ScrollView`. I want to have Scrollable content on my page, that also contains a List.

I initially wanted to display array of items with just `Label` without `ListView` or `CollectionView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 questions here

- `ListView` or `CollectionView` is using extra space.
- How to display a small array of items without `ListView` or `CollectionView`?

There is one solution to both the problems. Use a Layout such as `StackLayout` and set its `BindableLayout.ItemsSource` to your array, list or collection. Then Define its `ItemTemplate`.

**Here is the sample code:**

```xml
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

**Define your Array as in View or ViewModel (ViewModel is recommended):**

```cs
public string[] Fruits { get { return new string[] { "Mango", "Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Grapes" }; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to achieve this .

Just use `Label` without any Layout .

`<Label x:Name="label"/>`

---

#### Basic

We can add `\n` manually to make the label multiple lines.

```
 string text = "";

 foreach(var str in Fruits)
 {
    text += str + "\n";
 }
 label.Text = text;
```

[image]

---

#### Custom

To style the label we can use `FormattedText` .

```
FormattedString text = new FormattedString();
foreach(var str in Fruits)
{
   Span sp = new Span();
   sp.Text = str + "\n";
   sp.FontSize = 20;
   sp.LineHeight = 3;
   sp.TextColor = Color.Red;

   text.Spans.Add(sp);
}
label.FormattedText = text;
```

[image]